# Multithreading WebSockets

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket

## Background

I have implemented an adapter interface using the RPC protocol, but recently have been tasked with implementing the interface using a WebSocket listener. With RPC, I was easily able to start an RPC listener thread to listen for events on a separate thread, but I'm not finding it so simple when it comes to JSR356.

## The Question

I'm attempting to implement a Java WebSocket ClientEndpoint that connects to a subscription URI, but I want to do so in a manner that utilizes multi-threading. I've been having a hard time finding any examples where multi-threading is needed from a client endpoint perspective. Is this even possible?

I need the WebSocket message handler to handle messages without blocking the main thread. I have not implemented the message handler yet because I'm not sure how to go about creating it in a way to accomplish what I want. Can anyone help point me in a better direction? Here's what I have so far:

## EventHandler.java

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class EventHandler {

    private URI subscriptionURI;
    private Session clientSession;

    public EventHandler(URI subscriptionURI) throws URISyntaxException {
        this.subscriptionURI = subscriptionURI;
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to connect to the CADI WebSocket server.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void connect() throws Exception {

        // Grab the WebSocket container and attempt to connect to the subscription URI
        WebSocketContainer container =  ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        container.connectToServer(this, subscriptionURI);

    }

    /**
     * Closes the CADI WebSocket client session.
     */
    public void close() {

        try {

            // Close the client session if it is open
            if(clientSession != null && clientSession.isOpen())
                clientSession.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            LogMaster.getErrorLogger().error("Could not close the WebSocket client session. It may have been closed already.", e);
        }

    }

    @OnOpen
    public void socketOpened(Session session) {
        this.clientSession = session;
    }

}
```

Here is how I start a new thread to connect to the WebSocket. What are the implications of this, though? Are subsequent messages received on the WebSocket going to block the main thread still?

```
EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler(new URI("wss://localhost/Example"));
new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            eventHandler.connect();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            LogMaster.getErrorLogger().error("Could not start EventHandler.", e);
        }
    }
}.start();
```